# Can Solspace calendar have multiple times each day for an event?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar, events

Can Solspace calendar be setup to have multiple times a day per event?  I am looking at using it for movie listings where each movie will be shown for a different number of days and each day the movie might be shown a different number of times and at different times of the day from day to day.

Does anyone know if Solspace calendar can be setup to do this?

Comment: We have responded to your ticket in our Private Ticketing system. Also, I apologize for the autoresponder saying one of our staff members is unavailable - you can disregard that notice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. When you create an event, add a rule for each time of the day that the event is going to occur as well as what day of the week its happening on at said time. You can have multiple, inclusive days and times of day for an event:

https://solspace.com/documentation/calendar/images/calendar_cppublish_1.jpg

[Edited to make this into a proper answer setup]

Answer (score 0):

I am lead to believe it is absolutely doable. I'm eyeing that occurrences section on this page:

https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Just send them an email and they'll tell you for sure.

Comment: I sent them an message through their site yesterday but got an auto out of office email back saying not back until July 7th or something like that which is why I posted the question here.  I need some kind of answer for the project for tomorrow.

Comment: Ehhh I know a guy over their but he's not around right now. Hopefully someone who has this addon can answer this for you.